# Why negative margin on row in Bootstrap 3.4.1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have included Bootstrap 3.4.1 in the below HTML page through CDN.

**HTML Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 bg-primary">grid content</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 bg-primary">grid content</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 bg-primary">grid content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is simple: why does a row have a right and left margin of -15 pixels?

We can simply remove the right and left padding of the fluid container, this will create the same effect.